# Could a translation error lead to squares to not be considered as rectangles?

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, выбор-слова, этимология, математика

I'm reading a certain set of kindergarten/lower primary maths textbooks that is written by North American authors for a European company.

Whenever students are asked to identify the number of rectangles in a given picture, the answer booklet gives the number of oblongs instead of the number of rectangles.

While the topic may be too advanced for kindergarten students, the maths textbooks indeed explicitly say at the bottom of the first page of a textbook at the very first level to tell students that squares are special types of rectangles, where levels 1-4 are for kindergarten students.

Additionally, the accompany guide for teachers devotes a whole page of discussion as to how to teach that squares are special types of rectangles. There's even a paragraph about teaching to kindergarten students. The authors/some of the co-authors of the teacher guides are also authors/co-authors of the textbooks. They have also said that if students are taught that squares are not rectangles, then they will have misconceptions later.

Perhaps, the ones who wrote the answer booklets were not fluent in English while the ones who wrote the textbooks were.

For example

> [picture with 4 circles, 2 triangles, 3 square rectangles, 2 oblong rectangles for a total of 5 rectangles]
>
> Circle ___
>
> Triangle ___
>
> Square ___
>
> Rectangle ___

The answer key would give only the numbers:

> 4
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 2

So, the last line is wrong since it should be 5.

Could this happen in Russian? Or a Russian dialect? I mean, is there something specific about the translations of any of the following words 'rectangle, square, oblong, quadrilateral, quadrangle, parallelogram, trapezoid/trapezium, rhombus' that would cause such confusion? I guess the translator/s thought that when English speakers say 'rectangle', it means 'oblong in their language/dialect, but I don't see that as specifically a problem for this particular language.

By the way, are squares considered rectangles in Russia? Apparently, these things can vary by state, curricula, culture, time, etc. Please provide a document from the education department of your government or something.

P.S. I'm a monolinguist.

Related:

[Are kindergartners supposed to be steered from squares being rectangles?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13831/)

[In what curricula are “rectangles” defined so as to exclude squares?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13700/in-what-curricula-are-rectangles-defined-so-as-to-exclude-squares)

[Why do we have circles for ellipses, squares for rectangles but nothing for triangles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249741/why-do-we-have-circles-for-ellipses-squares-for-rectangles-but-nothing-for-tria)

[What are/should kids (be) taught about the colour of the sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394471)

Comment: How does this question is related to Russian language? Are authors Russians? Math is the same in all languages. Mistakes exist in textbooks in all languages.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks! Could be. I don't want to say the actual language out of fear of identification. But if we suppose the company for example is Russian, is there some aspect of the Russian language that would make it plausible that the mistake/s would be due to a translation error rather than a geometric misconception?

Comment: Anyway, I think, it is just a typo.

Comment: @Dmitry Actually, it's not a typo because the same mistake is echoed throughout most of the exercises. Based on your knowledge of the Russian language, you do not believe there is evidence to suggest that the error relates to translation rather than geometric misconception?

Comment: As I told you, math is the same in all languages. I am interested in modern physics and math, I read popular science literature, but I never heard anything like this. Sometimes errors could appear due to [false friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend), but I can't imagine corresponding Russian "false friend of square".

Comment: Most probably, the author of the answers was not very good at geometry. Technically, a square is a rectangle, but people are so used to the fact that square has its own name, they could easily count them separately. It has nothing to do with language. Also if you draw a square with one corner at the bottom, most people will tell that it is a diamond (ромб) and count it separately.

Comment: @AlexVB but in Russian unlike in English there's one word for both a class of shapes **прямоугольник** (rectangle), аnd a type of shape within this class **прямогугольник** (oblong [rectangle]), which could well be the source of difference in outlooks between speakers of the two languages and of difficulty in translation as well

Comment: It sounds like the person who wrote the exercises used the casual American English understanding of squares and rectangles rather than the one specified in the text. Most people understand rectangle to mean oblong and do not use the word oblong at all.

Comment: @Dmitriy 'math is the same in all languages' --> apparently not. see the [chinese stackexchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/29192/could-a-translation-error-lead-to-squares-to-not-be-considered-as-rectangles-m) version? you can't possibly profess to be an expert in all languages in this regard can you?

Answer (score 5):

I believe i would answer exactly as the answer key shows, which in your opinion is *incorrect*.

> *I guess the translator/s thought that when English speakers say
>   'rectangle', it means 'oblong in their language/dialect*

I do envision such a possibility.

In Russian square is *квадрат* while rectangle is *прямоугольник* (named *oblong rectangle* in your description).

Both *rectangle* and *oblong rectangle* are just *прямоугольник* and the latter is usually only understood as *oblong*, to the exclusion of a *square*.

Although technically *square* is an isolated case of a *rectangle*, conceptually in Russian speaking milieu they're usually treated as different shapes. This is what i remember from my school years and it's been a while since then.

Comment: Баян Купи-ка, thanks. May you please clarify your penultimate paragraph? It looks like a dependent clause/fragment/forgot term.

Comment: Also, it's not supposed to be a riddle. What do you mean? It's a standard exercise in the text. There are others like it.

Comment: if children aren't taught that square is a type of a rectangle they will have to figure that out

Comment: Also technically square (квадрат) is a kind of rectangle (прямоугольник) we never use rectangle to unite rectangular shapes. In this case we will say rectangular shapes (прямоугольные фигуры)

Comment: @Andrii, we do. In the geometry class at least.

Comment: @Dmitriy so you disagree with Баян Купи-ка ? Ostensibly Баян Купи-ка says 'yes' while you say 'no'.

Comment: @BCLC I don't remember why I wrote such comment, so I deleted it.